# Multiple outputs from single SP - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've been testing multiple theories but having issues. I've created an SP and a BAT command to export a file via BCP and send it to a third party. Normally I would BCP it within the SP, but due to server:folder connectivity, I'm trying to perform the %OUTFILE% within the BAT (If I'm over complicating it, let me know.)

I can't post entire code, so I'll psuedo replace it.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE
{{{populates a temp table}}}
SELECT {requirements} FROM #table;
SELECT {requirements2} FROM #table;
SELECT {requirements3} FROM #table;
END
```

Now this works in live form, just fine.

The BAT file I sent the client is

```
SET hourVAR
SET OUTFILE="{FileDirectory}"
bcp "exec SPICreated" queryout %OUTFILE% params
```

Normally I would do this either within a multiple step job (I can't do a job for them, though) or I would make the BAT file include the entire BCP "SELECT FROM" but the select is ~30 columns long, and due to the 3rd party vendor I'm trying to put all the 'bulk' in the SP.

Can anyone provide insight on how I may better do this? If I assign a variable to the "SELECT" portion, can I call it from the BAT file? SQL Server is not my forte.

(Trying not to create 3 duplicated SPs, and trying to avoid a ~100 line BAT file.)

--- For those wondering, running the SP with all 3 "SELECTs" caused it to become broken in compilation and somehow becomes.

Additional Info: This is all from the same table, but I need 3 different data sets in 3 different documents.

Data Resembles:

```
1|2|3|4|5
A|B|C|D|E
Z|X|Y|V|C
AA|BB|3|D|5
```

I need Document One to be

```
1|2|3
A|B|C
Z|X|Y
AA|BB|D
```

I need document Two to be

```
1|5
A|E
Z|C
AA|3
```

I need document Three to be

```
1|3
A|D
Z|V
AA|D
```

EDIT: Added data examples to assist query. Queries already work to get the data within a view, but not for BCP

Comment: Ummmm. You may want to revisit your title - [SQL Server History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server#History). If you think the version number is important, and once you've identified the correct one, we'd tend to advise that you add it as another *tag*. Tag's belong in the tags, not in the title.

Comment: If the `SELECT`s have the same structure, you can use `UNION ALL` to make them one result set. If they don't have the same structure, this can't work because `bcp` doesnt' support multiple result sets.

Comment: You're right - Corrected server. Sorry, normally work on 2005.